# What is the intuitive meaning behind a random variable being defined as a "lattice"?

Tags: probability

In probability theory, a nonnegative random variable $X$ is called a *lattice* if there exists $d \geq 0$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(X=nd) = 1$.

Is there a geometric interpretation for why this definition is called a lattice?

Answer (score 21):

It means that $X$ is discrete, *and* there is some kind of regular spacing to its distribution; that is, the probability mass is concentrated on a finite/countable set of points ${d, 2d, 3d, \dots}$.

Note that not all discrete distributions are lattices. Eg if $X$ can take on the values $\{1, e, \pi, 5\}$, this is not a lattice since there is no $d$ such that all the values can be expressed as multiples of $d$.

Answer (score 17):

This terminology connects the random variable with concepts of [group theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_theory) used to study geometric symmetries.  You might therefore enjoy seeing the more general connection, which will illuminate the meaning and potential applications of lattice random variables.

#### Background

In mathematics, a "lattice" $\mathcal{L}$ is a discrete subgroup of a topological group $G$ ([usually assumed to have a finite covolume](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice#Mathematics)).

- "Discrete" means that around each element $g\in\mathcal{L}$ is an open set $\mathcal{O}_g\subset\mathcal{L}$ containing only $g$ itself: $\mathcal{O}_g\cup\mathcal{L}=\{g\}$.  It would be fair to think of $\mathcal{L}$ as being a "patterned" or "regular" arrangement of points in $G$.
- The group $G$ acts on $\mathcal{L}$ by "moving points in $\mathcal{L}$ around in $G$," forming an *orbit* out of each one.  A [fundamental domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_domain) of this action consists of a single point in each orbit.  $G$ can be equipped with a measure--the Haar measure--used to measure the sizes, or *volumes*, of Borel measurable subsets of $G$.  A measurable fundamental domain can be found.  Its volume is the *covolume* of $\mathcal{L}$.  When it is finite, we can think of $G$ as being tiled by this fundamental domain and the elements of $\mathcal{L}$ as moving the tiles around.

[image: Figure: Sea Horse (No. 11), M. C. Escher]

*Any pair of these sea horse figures--where one is right side up and the other upside down--can be a fundamental domain for the visually evident lattice in the Euclidean plane.*  [M.C. Escher, *Sea Horse (No. 11)*.](http://www.mcescher.com/gallery/symmetry/no-11-sea-horse/)

**A "lattice" random variable $X$ is supported on a lattice in $(\mathbb{R}^n, {+})$.**  This means that all its probability is contained in the closure of the lattice.  Because a lattice is discrete, it is closed, so the values of $X$ are on the lattice almost surely: $\Pr(X\in\mathcal{L})=1$.

#### Application

The group implied by the question is the additive group of real numbers, $(\mathbb{R}, {+})$, with its usual (Euclidean) topology.  As a subgroup, a lattice $\mathcal{L}$ must include $0$.  That alone will not suffice, because the quotient $\mathbb{R}/\{0\}$ has infinite volume ("volume" = "length" in this 1D case).  Thus there is at least one nonzero element $g\in\mathcal{L}$.  All of the powers of this element must also be in the subgroup.  Since the operation is *addition*, the $n^\text{th}$ power of $g$ is $ng$.  Therefore $\mathcal{L}$ contains all integral multiples of $g$ (including the negative ones).

If there are two elements $h,g\in\mathcal{L}$ which are not powers of each other, it is easy to show (using a tiny bit of number theory) that (1) all the combinations $ng+mh$, for $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$, are in one-to-one correspondence with the ordered pairs $(m,n)$ and (2) these combinations are *dense* in $\mathbb{R}$, which would mean $\mathcal{L}$ is not discrete. From this it is straightforward to conclude that *all elements in $\mathcal{L}$ are powers of a single number $g$.*  This is the *generator* of $\mathcal{L}$.

(An analogous argument shows that lattices in $(\mathbb{R}^n, {+})$ must have $n$ generators.  Generators for the Escher watercolor could be, say, a translation of two units down and a translation one unit down and one unit to the right, approximately.)

Consequently, corresponding to any real-valued lattice random variable $X$ on $(\mathbb{R}, {+})$ must be a generator $g\ne 0$, whence

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \Pr(X=ng) \le \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \Pr(X=ng) = \Pr(X\in\mathcal{L}) = 1.$$

**The definition in the question therefore can be understood as that of a *non-negative* lattice variable.** We might also want to stipulate that $\Pr(X=0) \lt 1$, for otherwise $X$ is supported on the subgroup $\{0\}$ which, having infinite covolume, is not a lattice.

#### Generalization

The positive real numbers $(\mathbb{R}^{+}, {\times})$ form a multiplicative group.  A lattice on this group will be of the form $\mathcal{L} = \{g^n\,|\,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ for some $g \gt 0$.  (The covolume of this lattice is $|\log(g)|$.)  Accordingly, any random variable $Y$ for which

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \Pr(Y=g^n)  = 1$$

could be considered a lattice variable on this group.  Evidently, $\log(Y)$ would be a lattice variable on $(\mathbb{R}, {+})$.